# Is it true that $(3,1+\sqrt{-14})^2(2,\sqrt{-14})=(2-\sqrt{-14})$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-14}]$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals

I was trying to find the class group for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-14})$ and I ran into this issue that I could not resolve.

I was trying to see if $P_2^2P_1=(2-\sqrt{-14})$ where the underlying ring is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-14}]$ and $P_2=(3,1+\sqrt{-14}), P_1=(2,\sqrt{-14}).$ (These all denote the ideal generated by such elements)

I tried to compute a few 'obvious' elements in $P_2^2P_1$ and I found that they all in $(2-\sqrt{-14})$ but I couldn't find a way to convince that $2-\sqrt{-14}$ was in $P_2^2P_1$.

Could someone please give me a few hints? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This particular class group calculation is worked out as Example 3 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/classgpex.pdf. In particular, it's kind of irrelevant whether that *specific* equation you ask about holds.  All that matters is that $(2-\sqrt{-14})$ is divisible by just *one* of the prime ideals dividing $(3)$, not by both of them. That is good enough to know $(2-\sqrt{-14}) = \mathfrak p^2(2.\sqrt{-14})$ where $\mathfrak p$ is *some* prime ideal dividing $(3)$. I think your method in this example is too tedious if you're using explicit generators of the prime ideals.

Comment: @KCd Hey, I found your comment very useful! I think this deserves to be an answer as it completely solves my issue (you can just copy and paste if you will!). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Working in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-14}]$ with ideals with finite generators, the following might be helpful :

By definition we have that $IJ=\{a_1b_1+\cdots+a_nb_n~|~a_i\in I~\text{and}~b_i\in J ~\text{for every}~1\leq i\leq n ~\text{and for every}~n\geq 1\}$. So if the ideals $I,J$ are finitely generated, for example $I=(a,b)$ and $J=(x,y,z)$, the product $IJ$ is generated by all the possible products between the generators of each ideal. Namely, we have $IJ=(ax,ay,az,bx,by,bz)$
for our example. Now, you just calculate your case.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your point but this involves looking for $8$ generators, which is a quite long computation. I was wondering if there is a slicker, quicker way of doing it

Comment: @JustWandering To be quicker, maybe you can see without computing everything if in the final ideal an element in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-14}]-\mathbb{Z}$ and some integer occurs so that you showcase if your conjecture is correct or not. This although again needs you to do some calculations. Unfortunately, right now, I do not have another way of doing it in mind.